# Regular Expression within tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

In `tcl` I am giving this as:-

```
set promptInfo [oBOTANDROID2 launchVapiEiCmd getinfo]
```

and getting the output as"-

`VAPIEI Cmd Rcvd: {state inservice} {type dmc} {description {BOTSP2,10.77.41.154,tcp;(dmc)}} {lines 2} {calls 2} {streams 4} {{primary cm} 10.77.41.11} {{backup cm} } {status {}} {id dmc2} {userid } {{last error} {}} {{delay offer} false} {{Voice Mail client status} {inactive}} {{primary cti} {}} {{backup cti} {}} {{current cti} {}} {{preferred mode} {voip}} {{call type} {voip}} {{domain} {}} {{ixenabled} {no}} {{esrstvernego} {null}} {{ipv4address} {10.77.41.154}} {{ipv6address} {}} {{deploymentmodel} {on-premise}} {{login type} {uc-directory}} {centraluds {}} {{sip port} {42708}} {privacy disabled}`

Here I need to compare the two `ip` which is coming one with `BOTSP2` and other after `ipv4address`, both should be same.

How to extract the both IP addresses?

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the following code:

```
set a {VAPIEI Cmd Rcvd: {state inservice} {type dmc} {description {BOTSP2,10.77.41.154,tcp;(dmc)}} {lines 2} {calls 2} {streams 4} {{primary cm} 10.77.41.11} {{backup cm} } {status {}} {id dmc2} {userid } {{last error} {}} {{delay offer} false} {{Voice Mail client status} {inactive}} {{primary cti} {}} {{backup cti} {}} {{current cti} {}} {{preferred mode} {voip}} {{call type} {voip}} {{domain} {}} {{ixenabled} {no}} {{esrstvernego} {null}} {{ipv4address} {10.77.41.154}} {{ipv6address} {}} {{deploymentmodel} {on-premise}} {{login type} {uc-directory}} {centraluds {}} {{sip port} {42708}} {privacy disabled}}
regexp {BOTSP2,([\d.]+).*\{ipv4address\}\s*\{([\d.]+)} $a m ip1 ip2
 if {$ip1 eq $ip2} {
   puts "Equal!"
 }
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/5JWq5c)

The regex `BOTSP2,([\d.]+).*\{ipv4address\}\s*\{([\d.]+)` will match `BOTSP2,` and then capture into Group 1 one or more digits and dots (=`ip1`) and then it will find the `{ipv4address}`+spaces+`{` and then capture one or more digits and dots into Group 2 (`ip2`).

You can later check the strings for equality.

Comment: you have written like this  $a m ip1 ip2 ...what is m here?

Comment: `m` is the whole matched substring. `$a` is the input. `ipN` are submatches, captured texts.

Answer (score 0):

The output you are getting can very well be interpreted as a Tcl list, and thus you can use [`lsearch`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm):

```
% lsearch -regexp -inline $promptInfo "BOTSP2"
description {BOTSP2,10.77.41.154,tcp;(dmc)}
% lsearch -regexp -inline $promptInfo "ipv4address"
{ipv4address} {10.77.41.154}
```

The first result can be cleaned with `lindex` and split, while the second with a single `lindex`. If you want to get the IPs in one line:

```
% lindex [split [lindex [lsearch -regexp -inline $promptInfo "BOTSP2"] 1] ,] 1
10.77.41.154
% lindex [lsearch -regexp -inline $promptInfo "ipv4address"] 1
10.77.41.154
```

After which you can compare them.